# Flower Shop Online Database Schema - correct entity connections?

Tags: database-design

I'm doing an web database app--flower shop online--where a person can order bouquets for people important to them and have the bouquets delivered to those people by a courier. I'm having a problem with the database schema. I can't connect entities the right way--connections are creating paradoxes and are very inefficient. This is the database schema:

[image: click here to see the schema]

I'm having problems with connecting entities from SPEC_BUKIET to FLOWER. Database assumptions:

1. Each kind of bouquet (entity BOUQUET_KIND) can have bouquets in different sizes
2. Bouquets of different sizes (entity SPEC_BUKIET) and of the same kind have different prices
3. Bouquets of different sizes and of the same kind have different quantities of flowers of the same kind used in them (e.g. a small bouquet uses 2 roses and 2 tulips, a medium bouquet uses 4 roses and 4 tulips, a large bouquet uses 8 roses and 8 tulips) (entity BOUQUET_FLOWER)
4. Flowers of the same kind used in bouquets can have a different length and color (entity FLOWER)

With a database designed like in the schema I'm getting a paradox where bouquets of the same kind in different sizes could have totally different flowers assigned and the SQL query to select flowers used in bouquets becomes complicated. What is an easier way to solve relationships in the schema?

Comment: I think this is overly broad for stackoverflow.  I suggest you research "Bill of Materials" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials it may help find the right approach.  Ultimately is sounds like you're designing an ERP system,  maybe something like Microsoft Dynamics would be a better approach for you.

Comment: Please give a reference to the particular modeling method you are following. Please use text whenever you can. Ie for the entire content of this diagram. But please include only what is relevant to your question. Within such a subset isolate the parts of your design that you think are correct from the parts that you think are problematic. Explain how you followed the design method you are following to get what you got.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that you've made BOUQUET_SIZE an attribute of SPEC_BUKIET. There's nothing wrong with this, but it sounds like you have a concept of varying BOUQUET_SIZE without changing anything else, which doesn't match your model. Probably what you want is to add an object BOUQUET_INSTANCE:

```
BOUQUET_INSTANCE MANY:1 SPEC_BUKIET
BOUQUET_INSTANCE MANY:1 BOUQUET_SIZE
BOUQUET_INSTANCE 1:MANY BOUQUET_FLOWER
```